Run Agent automatically for self hosted yaml pipelines in Azure DevOps
I  have a self-hosted agent that goes idle if no jobs for max two hours, so the pipeline have to perform agentless or server job that open ssh session and get the server up. Is it feasible?

You can use the Scheduled triggers in the pipeline. For example, you could set up a pipeline to run at regular intervals, such as every hour, which opens ssh session and gets the server up.
YAML:
schedules:
- cron: string # cron syntax defining a schedule
  displayName: string # friendly name given to a specific schedule
  branches:
    include: [ string ] # which branches the schedule applies to
    exclude: [ string ] # which branches to exclude from the schedule
  always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.
  batch: boolean # Whether to run the pipeline if the previously scheduled run is in-progress; the default is false.
  # batch is available in Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 and higher

Run every hour:
trigger:
  none  

schedules:
- cron: "0 * * * *"  # every hour
  displayName: Every Hour
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  always: true



If you are using the classic pipeline, you can select the days and times when you want to run the build using the classic editor.

